# GraphQL - Get Mutual Friends

Tags: graphql

How would I get mutual friends using a GraphQL API?

I can find a lot of resources on how to do this in SQL or Cypher, but not GraphQL.

We could use [Hasura](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/postgres/queries/index.html) in this example, or any GraphQL API.

Schema:

```js
type Person {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  friends: [Person]
}
```

We have two people with ids `01` and `02`.

What would the GraphQL for this be? Is it possible without under-the-hood functionality or child / nested filters?

Comment: @meagar - why are you removing the mutual friend tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample query I believe would work...

```json
query {
  queryPerson(filter: {
    and: [
      { friends: { id: ['0x1'] } }
      { friends: { id: ['0x2'] } }
    ]
  ) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

J